# JQuery - не правильно обрабатывает значения массива после 9

Tags: jquery, map, массивы, php

Всем привет.
Не знаю, правильно ли описал в заголовке.
В общем проблема такая.

php скрипт возвращает следующее

```
{"items":1,"views":"1,2,3,7,8,9,10,11"}
```

Если я делаю

```
$.each(data.views, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

То мне выводит

```
1 
, 
2 
, 
3 
, 
7 
, 
8 
, 
9 
, 
1 
0 
, 
1
```

При этом ни 10, ни 11 не срабатывают. Они у меня должны скрывать дивы. Все скрывает до 10.
Если есть 10 или больше, то обрабатывает не правильно.

Что я делаю не так? Пробовал вместо each использовать map - результат то же.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MM82Z/
выдает ошибку

Comment: короче, у вас там не массив, а строка, и скрипт проходит по каждому символу в строке, как по элементу массива. именно для этого люди придумали json

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел. Там php возвращает echo json_encode($items_array);.
$items_array - массив.

В AJAX запросе тип указан dataType: "json",

Comment: ну значит, вероятно, items выглядит так: array('items'=>integer,'views'=>string). откуда взялась строка -- понятия не имею

Comment: Нашел! Спасибо.

Да. Там через implode(',', $array) возвращало в глубине кода.

Убрал и все заработало без split.

Странно, почему так сделали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию `.split()`. В вашем примере:

```
var myarray=data.views.split(',');
myarray==[1,2,3,7,8,9,10,11]//true
```

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало наконец. Понял теперь почему не работало)